# Applying a patch at runtime in Maven

Tags: maven, patch, giraph

I'm trying to install Giraph 1.1 but ran into an issue. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45502386/2992391) I should apply a [patch](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-patch-plugin/) to my installation. Unfortunately, my problem stems from that. I downloaded and copied the `.patch` file linked in there to the source folder and added the following to the `pom.xml`:

```
<plugins>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-patch-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <patches>
        <patch>GIRAPH-1110.02.patch</patch>
      </patches>
...
</plugins>
```

Unfortunately when I run Maven with:

```
sudo mvn -Phadoop_yarn -Dhadoop.version=2.8.1 clean package -DskipTests
```

it still fails with the same error as it did before:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /usr/local/giraph/giraph-core/target/munged/main/org/apache/giraph/job/GiraphJob.java:[213,11] setPingInterval(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,int) is not public in org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client; cannot be accessed from outside package
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Giraph Parent ............................... SUCCESS [  6.298 s]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Core ................................. FAILURE [  9.359 s]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.062 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-06T22:53:00+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 51M/640M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project giraph-core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /usr/local/giraph/giraph-core/target/munged/main/org/apache/giraph/job/GiraphJob.java:[213,11] setPingInterval(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,int) is not public in org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client; cannot be accessed from outside package
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

which clearly shows that the issue has not been patched. When I check the file manually, I can confirm that there's no change. If I change the file manually before compilation, the changes get discarded (I'm guessing the file gets redownloaded). Also can't run the installation with offline flag since it depends on downloading some dependencies. I'm at my wits end here.

My Maven version is 3.3.9.

Comment: Instead of manually patching things you should search for an more recent version in Central and use that instead ....

Comment: @user2992391   any solution found?